# Kafka Real-Time guarantees

Tags: apache-kafka, real-time

Can Kafka gurantee that a consumer sees the message x ms after it has been (successfully) produced?

### Background:

I have a system, where service A accepts requests. Service B needs to be able to answer how many requests have been coming in by a certain time. Service B needs to be precise. My plan is:

- Service A accepts requests, it produces a message and waits for the ack of at least one replica. As it got it, it will send the user that it's request is "in the system".
- As Service B is asked, I wait x ms. Then I check the topic for new requests. So I know 100% the state of Service A at "now() - x ms".

In this case, Kafka needs to guarantee that I can consume a message maximum X ms after it has been produced. Is that the case?

Comment: The semantics are different if you are talking about "time after produced" and "time after acknowledged". After acknowledgement, you can set it up so the message is immediately available to be consumed. The high watermark goes up after the minimum number of in sync replicas are satisfied and you can consume it. Some more background here about replication and the implications of it. Does that help? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_ha

Comment: It helped. I improved my question to give a better understanding. Still, I am not sure. That means, if I wait till one replica acknowledges the produced message, it is always there for consumption, right?

Comment: It will be available for consumption of you have min.insync.replicas set to 1 on the topic (default). If you set this higher, you'll have to wait longer potentially for the durability guarantee you are imposing.

Comment: Sounds reasonable for me and answers the question imho. If you want to, you can summarize it in an answer, then I'll accept it.

Comment: Did my best to summarize :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka, messages are available for consumption once the high watermark has been incremented. This is guaranteed to happen after the minimum number of in sync replicas has been satisfied. The trade-off here is durability for latency. If you require lower latency, only acknowledging at the leader is faster. However, this isn't as durable as waiting for 2 in sync replicas. When answering "when can I consume?", you are really answering "when has the message been acknowledged as written by Kafka?"